# Get Items Filter Counting First Row as Header

Tags: power-automate

Genuinely not understanding the issue here. My goal is to retrieve in the 2nd 'Get Items' action a filtered list of items that exist in both lists. This way, the remaining items returned by Get Items will be only those in the list Restock Notifications that are also in the list Restock.

[image]

This is failing because the Filter Query is considering the first row to be the Column header, but MS documentation isn't helping me understand how to write the filter otherwise.

[image]

How do I designate RestockNbr and ItemNumber in the Filter Query to be the column headers?

Comment: Make sure you are using correct [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of your RestockNbr column. If this column is of type text, wrap `ItemNumber` inside single quotes like: `RestockNbr eq 'ItemNumber'`. Let me know if this works for you.